# terraform/gcp - how to enable iam.googleapis.com with TF

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

Please help understand how to enable GCP IAM API using Terraform.

### Environment

```
$ terraform --version
Terraform v1.0.4
on linux_amd64
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/google v4.6.0
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/time v0.7.2
```

### Resource

```
resource "google_project_service" "iam" {
  project = data.google_project.project.project_id
  service = "iam.googleapis.com"
  timeouts {
    create = "20m"
    update = "20m"
  }
  disable_dependent_services = false
  disable_on_destroy         = false
}
```

### Error

Run `terraform apply` but it keeps repeating the error message.

```
Error: Error creating service account: googleapi: Error 403: Identity and Access Management (IAM) API has not been used in project 450605631931 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/iam.googleapis.com/overview?project=450605631931 then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.
│ Details:
│ [
│   {
│     "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.Help",
│     "links": [
│       {
│         "description": "Google developers console API activation",
│         "url": "https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/iam.googleapis.com/overview?project=450605631931"
│       }
│     ]
│   },
│   {
│     "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
│     "domain": "googleapis.com",
│     "metadata": {
│       "consumer": "projects/450605631931",
│       "service": "iam.googleapis.com"
│     },
│     "reason": "SERVICE_DISABLED"
│   }
│ ]
│ , accessNotConfigured
│ 
│   with google_service_account.gke,
│   on sa.tf line 14, in resource "google_service_account" "gke":
│   14: resource "google_service_account" "gke" {
```

The GCP console says it is enabled.

[image]

Comment: Hey, have you solved that one?

Comment: Run into the same error but IAM API is enabled for the project. I wonder did you find the solution?

Comment: Did you guys figure out a solution?

Comment: Can you check if the Service Usage API (serviceusage.googleapis.com) is enable? Also, You need to run that specific version of Terraform/providers?

Answer (score 0):

Given that this line is throwing the error:

```
on sa.tf line 14, in resource "google_service_account" "gke":
│   14: resource "google_service_account" "gke" {
```

You need to update the `google_service_account` resource block to wait for the API activation resource block:

```
resource "google_service_account" "gke" {
 depends_on = [google_project_service.iam]
 ...
}
```